# 3-way merge in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, merge, three-way-merge

Does anyone know of an Open Source three-way merge implementation in JavaScript or PHP? I want to merge plain text files without the need to rely on any server side binaries.

I found a few solutions for creating diffs, but no merge implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Synchrotron](http://homepages.kcbbs.gen.nz/tonyg/projects/synchrotron.html) looks good.  E.g. see the [demo of three-way merge and conflict-handling](http://hg.opensource.lshift.net/synchrotron/raw-file/default/diff3demo.html).

Comment: Synchrotron seemed to have some bugs when merging for me, but it may work for you. I'd be interested if there are any other JavaScript libraries

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly three-way merge, but Google's ["Diff Match and Patch libraries offer robust algorithms to perform the operations required for synchronizing plain text"](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). And the implementation is available in Java, JavaScript, C++, C#, Lua and Python.

Comment: This is the best answer. While I understand links are not desired on SO, the authors of `diff-match-patch` provide an example of a 3-way merge that may be helpful for others using this library: https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/demos/patch.html

Answer (score 1):

Just finished my work on such a js- and php-tool. Have a look and enjoy:

https://github.com/Krassmus/Textmerger

You'd just need to write

```
var merged = Textmerger.get().merge(original, mytext, theirtext);
```

or in PHP

```
$merged = Textmerger::get()->merge($original, $mytext, $theirtext);
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

After finding that the npm packages 3-way-merge and three-way-merge (the main ones that show up in search results for "three way merge npm") didn't work well, and are not maintained, I stumbled upon this much larger more helpful

https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff3

We ended up writing our solution like so:

```
var diff3 = require('diff3');
var mergeData = diff3(sourceArray, originalArray, targetArray);

var result = mergeData.map(({ok, conflict}) => {
  if (ok) {
    return ok;
  }
  else if (conflict) {
    return [
      '<<<<<<< target',
      ...conflict.b,
      '>>>>>>> target',
      '<<<<<<< source',
      ...conflict.a,
      '>>>>>>> source'
    ];
  }
}).flat();
```

Comment: We are meant to close (and not answer) questions which seek software recommendations.